# Subspaces of $\{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ continuous}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having a hard time grasping vector spaces and subspaces. I'm trying to solve these questions and I know there are axioms to satisfy but I am unsure how to put them into effect.

Show that $\{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ continuous}\}$ with operations

$(f+g)(t) = f(t)+g(t)$

$(rf)(t) = rf(t)$

is a vector space. Call it $V$.

(i) Let $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $W = \{f \in V  \mid f(t_0) = 0\}$

Show that $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

(ii) Let $U = \{f \in V \mid f(t^2) = (f(t))^2 \text{ for all }t \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Show that $U$ is not a subspace of $V$.

(iii) Let $X = \{f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ differentiable}$} and show that $X$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Check your vector space axioms – commutativity and associativity of addition, existence of additive identity, existence of additive inverses, associativity of scalar multiplication, distributivity of scalar sums, and distributivity of vector sums.

Comment: These are relatively hard vector space questions.  Have you done plenty of examples in ${\Bbb R}^2$, ${\Bbb R}^3$ etc?

Comment: @Shailesh: Closure under vector addition and scalar multiplication are still needed for (i), even though they're trivial to show.

Comment: @Frentos  Right. Sorry about that.

Comment: Just a note for the future: you can actually stay in math mode for a really long time. There's no need to wrap dollar signs around $f$, $\in$, and $\Bbb R$ individually in a statement like $f \in \Bbb R$ (`$f \in \mathbb{R}$`). Not only is it *much* easier for you to use way fewer dollar signs, but the software has less work (meaning noticeably quicker loading, once you've written enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove something is a subspace, it must be shown that it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication (and also that the subset is contained within the space).

**Solution**

(i) Let $f,g \in W$, and $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $(f+g)$ is continuous. Since it is known that $f(t_0) = 0$ and $g(t_0)=0$, then $(f+g)(t_0) = f(t_0) + g(t_0) = 0$. Therefore $(f+g) \in W$, so $W$ is closed under vector addition.

Since $f$ is continuous, then $kf$ is continuous. Since it is known that $f(t_0) = 0$, then $(kf)(t_0) = kf(t_0) = 0$ . Therefore $kf \in W$, so $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

$W$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, so it is a subspace of $V$.

(ii) Consider $f(t) = t$.

Then $f$ is continuous, and $f(t^2) = t^2 = (f(t))^2$, so $f \in U$. Then $(2f)(t^2) = 2f(t^2) = 2t^2$ but $((2f)(t))^2 = 2^2f(t)^2 = 4t^2$, so $2f \notin U$.

$U$ is not closed under scalar multiplication, so it is not a subspace of $V$.

(iii) Since any differentiable $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also continuous, then $X \subset V$.

Since the sum of two differentiable functions is differentiable, $X$ is closed under vector addition. Since a differentiable function multiplied by a scalar is differentiable, $X$ is closed under scalar multiplication. So $X$ is a subspace of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

1) Given 2 functions $f,g$ such that for any fixed $t_0\in \mathbb{R}, f(t_0)=g(t_0)=0$, we see that the function sum $f+g$ is such that $f(t_0)+g(t_0)=0$, so this set is closed under sum, and for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$
$r(f(t_0))=r.0=0$, then the set is closed under scalar multiplication therefore 
this is subspace.

2) supposse the funtions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, their sum $x+x^2$ don´t hold the propertie, so this is not a subspace.

3) The last is only use that $(f+g)\prime=f\prime +g\prime$ and $(kf)\prime=kf\prime.$